# Shell Sort Minimum Comparisons

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, shellsort

What is the minimum number of comparisons needed by shell sort to sort a list of 8 items, given a gap list of `5,1`?

I understand that the best case performance is an `n(log(n))` case, but I can't work through the maths to get the full expression needed to put the given numbers in to get the minimum number of comparisons.

Comment: You should walk us through what you've done, and highlight where your gap is.

Comment: Hmm, [cs.se] might be a better home for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, one speaks of asymtotic time when the number of elements is arbitrary big therefore `n`. When you have a exact number of elements, their number is constant. Therefore it is `O(1)`.

Only in general it is BC `O(n log n)` for processing "`n`" elements. However, one is usually more interested in WC.

Here you need to work it out either by hand or write a simple program calculating them.

From the pseudocode:

```
# Sort an array a[0...7].
gaps = [5, 1]
foreach (gap in gaps) {
    for (i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
        temp = a[i]
        for (j = i; j >= gap and a[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)
            a[j] = a[j - gap]

            a[j] = temp
    }
}
```

Plugging in the numbers is now straightforward.

Just for the sake of doing it, since you don't know the values of the elements you can only look it at WC. From the code above for the gap `5` we have `5,6,7` then the inner loop is also executed once for each of them, because of `j = i; j >= gap; j -= gap`. For gap `1` you have `1..7` in the outer for-loop and then you decrease for every execution (WC!) with 1. All in all you have:

> gap(5) + gap(1) = (1 + 1 + 1) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) = 31

Comment: Thanks for that. Just to confirm could you work through the numbers for say a list of 10 items with a gap list of 3,1?

Comment: just plug them in the pseudocode, first `gap = 3`  then in `for (i = 3; i < 10; i += 1) ` and further you can see how it develops just by plugging `n = 10` and first `gap` 3 and when the first for loop (not the `foreach`) finishes, plug in the next gap, the 1.

Comment: Something is very wrong in your examples. A 5-gap sort will always result in n-5 comparisons when n=8. the 1-gap sort (insertion sort) can - at best - sort using n-1 comparisons when n=8 and that is when the result of the 5-gap sort is a nearly sorted input sequence.

Comment: This answer is wong. Minimum comparisons (best case) refers to a sorted list. With gap 1 it is n-1 (so 8-1=7 comparisons), and for gap 5 there are 3 comparisons. That's 10 comparisons in total.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The problem in the analysis was the fact that I overlookingly based 'n' on the highest array index (7) and not the total number of elements (8). Then for 5-gap is '3'. For the 1-gap, we have to include the case, when *i = 7* in the outer loop and respectively run the the inner loop 7 more times in WC ('a[j - gap] > temp' being true, while 'j -= 1').

Answer (score 0):

For the minimum number of comparisons required by shellsort you would need to input a nearly sorted vector specifically tailored to the chosen gap sequence.

The last step of a shellsort is an insertion sort. No other sorting method is faster than insertion sort when you input sorted data, it requires only n-1 comparisons.

The idea behind shellsort is to pre-sort values that are far apart so that the "ground is paved" for the insertion sort to perform as few comparisons as possible. A reversed input sequence is the most comparison-costly for insertion sort, it requires n*(n-1)/2 comparisons. If you do a pre-sort - regardless of gap sequence - the final insertion sort will require less comparisons than using an insertion sort by itself. However, it is when you sum up the number of comparisons in the pre-sort(s) and add them to the comparisons in the final insertion sort that you find out if you managed to better the results of a basic insertion sort.

There are two sequences (s) of data - given n=8 - that require the same number of comparisons in an insertion sort:

```
"01234567" and
"10234567" though this causes a swap of "1" and "0"
```

In any case, both require n-1 => 7 comparisons.

When we add the 5-gap it will add 3 comparisons: s[0] with s[5], s[1] with s[6] and s[2] with s[7]. Given the two insertion sort vectors mentioned previously we find that the comparisons should be the following to pave the way for a minimum comparison insertion sort:

```
s[0] with s[5] - "0"w"5" and "5"w"0" xor "1"w"5" and "5"w"1"
s[1] with s[6] - "1"w"6" and "6"w"1" xor "0"w"6" and "6"w"0"
s[2] with s[7] - "2"w"7" and "7"w"2"
```

Because the first two comparison cases have "0" and "1" in common you can't have "0" in both or "1" in both. If "0" is part of the first comparison then "1" is part of the second and vice versa.

This gives the following sequences to achieve a minimum (3+7) comparison shellsort when gap = {5,1} and n=8:

```
                      5-gap                               1-gap (insertion sort)
"01234567" - 0 swaps
"01734562" - 1 swaps:                         "7"w"2"
"06234517" - 1 swaps:             "6"w"1"
"06734512" - 2 swaps:             "6"w"1" and "7"w"2"
"51234067" - 1 swaps: "5"w"0"
"51734062" - 2 swaps: "5"w"0" and             "7"w"2"
"56234017" - 2 swaps: "5"w"0" and "6"w"1"
"56734012" - 3 swaps: "5"w"0",    "6"w"1" and "7"w"2"
"10234567" - 1 swaps:                                     "1"w"0"
"10734562" - 2 swaps:                         "7"w"2" and "1"w"0"
"16234507" - 2 swaps:             "6"w"0" and             "1"w"0"
"16734502" - 3 swaps:             "6"w"0",    "7"w"2" and "1"w"0"
"50234167" - 2 swaps: "5"w"1" and                         "1"w"0"
"50734162" - 3 swaps: "5"w"1",                "7"w"2" and "1"w"0"
"56234107" - 3 swaps: "5"w"1",    "6"w"0" and             "1"w"0"
"56734102" - 4 swaps: "5"w"1",    "6"w"0",    "7"w"2" and "1"w"0"
```

In all, 16 sequences resulting in a minimum comparison shellsort out of a total of 8! or 40320 possible sequences.

Of the possible 2^(n-2) or 64 possible gap sequences when n=8, {5,1} is best (@ 17.4 comparisons on average), closely followed by {6,1}, {7,5,1}, {7,4,1}, {4,1} and {3,1} in that order. They all require an average of less than 18 comparisons each. Insertion sort requires 19.3 comparisons on average.

Other characteristics of these gap sequences (insertion sort included for comparison):

```
                    number of comparisons
                    in a                             when
gap sequence        minimum sort      maximum sort   input sequence reversed
{1} (insertion sort)        7                28                    28
{3,1}                      12                24                    19
{4,1}                      11                26                    20
{5,1}                      10                24                    15
{6,1}                       9                25                    16
{7,4,1}                    12                24                    15
{7,5,1}                    11                23                    17
```